# Excel - Matching data to provide output

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to match the cell data from one column to another column that will have somehwere the same data in a cell. Once matched I want the two cells in the next two rows to be given next to the intial cell. See below for more info. How would I do this? Thank you for your help:

As you can can see in the image I want to search for the info in A2 in column E. Once this info has been found in E I want the corresponding rows in F and G tp be inserted into C2 and D2. Is this possible?

[image: Snapshot of excel doc]

Comment: This is possible, but your usernames columns don't contain any matching values, so can try to explain what you want more elaborately?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1)! It was designed specifically for this.

What I recommend you do first is split the two tables up, since they currently appear to be adjacent. Place them apart from each other with a one cell gap or put one of them on a second worksheet. After that, format each table (scores and users) using the 'Format as Table' feature to give them range references, and then you can exploit Excel's automatic formatting and formula completion. After that, using `VLOOKUP` should be super simple.

Here is an example spreadsheet with a few users and scores. You can see that for user 'ggg' there is no matching name, so the formula gives a #N/A error. You can extend the formula with `ISERROR` to make those blank if necessary.

[image]

In detail, the formula for column C is

`=VLOOKUP([@Username], Table1, 2,)`

`[@Username]` means it's using the column name for this table. Alternatively you could just use the actual cell reference. In this case, it's A2.

`Table1` is the reference to the entire users table in blue. You could use a cell range instead. In this case, it's F2:H7.

`2` is the column number you in the lookup table that you want to use. In this case, column 2 is the Firstname. For Lastname, it's 3.

(The omitted last parameter, `exactmatch` is false by default. If your data is clean, keep it as false.